# SQL Query Riddle

Tags: sql, group-by, left-join

I have an assignment which I cannot complete. These are the requierements:

Get the full list of people (even if the have not participated in any movies), showing the country, the name and date of birth, the number of movies in which said person has participated as an actor, and the number of films in which said person has participated as a screenwriter, ordered by country and descendent by date of birth.

An this is what I´ve come up with so far:

```
SELECT person_name, person_country, person_dob, COUNT (DISTINCT movie_name) WHERE role_name='Actor' OR role_name='Guionista' GROUP BY role_name
FROM movies.tb_person LEFT JOIN movies.tb_movie_person 
ON tb_person.person_id = tb_movie_person.person_id
LEFT JOIN movies.tb_role
ON tb_role.role_id = tb_movie_person.role_id;
```

Any ideas where I went wrong?

Kind Regards

Comment: Hint:  `LEFT JOIN`.  conditional aggregation.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: thanks for the answers,but still not getting there. @Gordon, my impression is that the mistake lies on the COUNT clause, the moment I get rid of this the rest of the querey works...

Comment: Please give a [mcve]. That's DBMS, version, a clear specification, cut & paste & runnable code (including input) (with table initializations formatted as tables) & diffable (hence ordered) desired output. But absolute basics of debugging say: Show that your program does what you expect as it goes through (sub)expressions by saying what that is & showing that it actually does it via incremental output. Research (in the manual & the web) re minimal additional code giving a problem that you can't solve. Then ask re the (small) difference between working & non-working examples.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @tb_Person table(person_sid int not null, person varchar(80));
declare @tb_Person_Movie table(person_sid int not null, role_sid int not null);
declare @tb_Role table(role_sid int not null, [role] varchar(80));

insert into @tb_Role values(1,'Actor');
insert into @tb_Role values(2,'Screenwriter');

insert into @tb_Person values(1,'Al Pacino');
insert into @tb_Person values(2,'Bob deNiro');
insert into @tb_Person values(3,'Mickey Rourke');
insert into @tb_Person values(4,'Jodie Foster');

insert into @tb_Person_Movie values(1, 1);--al pacino actor
insert into @tb_Person_Movie values(2, 1);--bob deniro actor
insert into @tb_Person_Movie values(3, 2);--mickey rourke screenwriter
--jodie none

select
    p.person_sid,
    p.person,
    SUM(case when r.[role] = 'Actor' then 1 else 0 end) AsActor,
    SUM(case when r.[role] = 'Screenwriter' then 1 else 0 end) AsScreenwriter
from 
    @tb_Person p
    left join @tb_Person_Movie pm on pm.person_sid = p.person_sid
    left join @tb_Role r on pm.role_sid = r.role_sid
group by 
    p.person_sid, p.person, r.[role]
```

Comment: it is SQL, specifically T-SQL for Microsoft SQL Server 2012 and on. Just grab the logic and replace with your tables and columns.